# Firebase Sign In - Rest API Common Errors

Tags: javascript, rest, api, firebase

I am currently playing around with Firebase Rest API Sign In, using the following code:

```
const authUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=${process.env.FBAPIKEY}`

  return this.$axios.$post(authUrl, {
    email: authData.email,
    password: authData.password,
    returnSecureToken: true
  })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

This is working a treat, however, I am purposely entering the wrong email address to test the error responses. I am receiving an error but all it says is:

> Request failed with status code 400

Why aren't I receiving more in-depth error responses such as:

> Error: Your email address does not exist

From reading the docs which can be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password we should be able to receive the following error properties

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound",
        "message": "File not found {fileId}"
      }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "File not found: {fileId}"
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

My Bad.. I needed to console.log(err.response)